# css width property not applying properly

Tags: css

As you can see there are three table cells with name price and quantity classes inside tr. I have given each of them width of 30%. So they should cover 90% of the page but it looks like the three of them aren't even covering half of the page.Though when I do give each of them widths that adds up to 100% they actually do  work but I want them to cover 90% of the page which doesn't seems to work as you can see in the code snippet.

```css
 #flexing .welcome  .note {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#flexing .welcome .checkout {
  margin:10px;
}

#flexing .welcome .cart a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:15.5px;
}

#flexing .welcome table .name {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .price {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .quantity {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexing">
  <div class="welcome">
    <h3>CHECK OUT</h3>
    <div class="cart"><a href="storenav/cart.html">5.00 EUR</a></div>
    <div class="note">
      <div class="checkout">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="name">Name</td>
              <td class="price">Price</td>
              <td class="quantity">Quantity<td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Faction | Hero rank</td>
              <td>5.00 EUR</td>
              <td class="button">1 
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody> 
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS to your table and make it's width 100%(or 90%).

```css
#flexing .welcome  .note {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#flexing table {
  width: 100%;
}

#flexing .welcome .checkout {
  margin:10px;
}

#flexing .welcome .cart a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:15.5px;
}

#flexing .welcome table .name {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .price {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .quantity {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexing">
  <div class="welcome">
    <h3>CHECK OUT</h3>
    <div class="cart"><a href="storenav/cart.html">5.00 EUR</a></div>
    <div class="note">
      <div class="checkout">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="name">Name</td>
              <td class="price">Price</td>
              <td class="quantity">Quantity<td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Faction | Hero rank</td>
              <td>5.00 EUR</td>
              <td class="button">1 
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody> 
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution, you need to provide 100% width to the table

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
}

 #flexing .welcome  .note {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#flexing .welcome .checkout {
  margin:10px;
}

#flexing .welcome .cart a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:15.5px;
}

#flexing .welcome table .name {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .price {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .quantity {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexing">
  <div class="welcome">
    <h3>CHECK OUT</h3>
    <div class="cart"><a href="storenav/cart.html">5.00 EUR</a></div>
    <div class="note">
      <div class="checkout">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="name">Name</td>
              <td class="price">Price</td>
              <td class="quantity">Quantity<td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Faction | Hero rank</td>
              <td>5.00 EUR</td>
              <td class="button">1 
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody> 
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must set a `width` for `table`:  table {   width: 100%; }

```css
table {
 width: 100%;
}
#flexing .welcome  .note {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

#flexing .welcome .checkout {
  margin:10px;
}

#flexing .welcome .cart a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:15.5px;
}

#flexing .welcome table .name {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .price {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}

#flexing .welcome table .quantity {
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexing">
  <div class="welcome">
    <h3>CHECK OUT</h3>
    <div class="cart"><a href="storenav/cart.html">5.00 EUR</a></div>
    <div class="note">
      <div class="checkout">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="name">Name</td>
              <td class="price">Price</td>
              <td class="quantity">Quantity<td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Faction | Hero rank</td>
              <td>5.00 EUR</td>
              <td class="button">1 
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
                <a href="#">aa</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody> 
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```