# CSS Width not Applying

Tags: css, width

Why are my `p`s of different widths for the code below?

I've tried wrapping them in a table and adding `width:100%` as per [css width property not applying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313477/css-width-property-not-applying-properly) but that didn't help.

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

p {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  color: white;
  height: 90px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop):

> table, inline-table, table-row-group, table-column, table-column-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-cell, and table-caption
>   These values cause an element to behave like a table element (**subject to restrictions** described in the chapter on tables).

Basically you are facing some default behavior of tables.

Here is an example to illustrate a similar situation:

```css
td {
 width:100px; /* This is restricted by the width of table*/
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of tables simply rely on something else

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
.container {
  font-size:0; /* remove white space */
  white-space:nowrap; /* Keep one line */
}
p {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  height: 90px;
  line-height:90px; /*vertical align */
  display:inline-block;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I used `table-cell` because several answers on here said that was a good way to get vertical alignment. It makes no sense to me to use something called `line-height` to vertically align within an element. But hey, it works, so thanks.

Comment: @Robin it make perfect sense. line-height is one among a lot of method that allow you to center content and it's the easiest one in your case since you deal with fixed height and one line. If you don't like it you can consider different method, ex: https://jsfiddle.net/8dev5pca/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using table styling, you can do what you suggested by wrapping the table cells in a table, applying a width of 100% and setting the `table-layout` to `fixed`. The fixed table layout will prevent the default auto width behavior of table cells.

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
p {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  height: 90px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
.table {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<p>0</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```